# How to train/use the HOGDescriptor class in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, pattern-matching

I have been looking into training/using OpenCV to attempt to detect human figures. I want to try training a HOG for my specific purposes and not use the provided getDefaultPeopleDetector function. I have been unable to find any usable documentation on the HOGDescriptor class.

How do I train my own classifier for my own purposes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HOG descriptor is very easy to implement. You can write your own code to do it. Look at http://smsoftdev-solutions.blogspot.com/2009/08/integral-histogram-for-fast-calculation.html.
It is fast implementation of HOG. Once you get HOG features of all the training images.You can train an SVM in OpenCV. Training with Gaussian Kernel has produced good results.

Comment: -1.  The OP asked how to use HOGDescriptor class in OpenCV, not how to implement it.  This is a very valid question, because 5 years later it's still poorly documented so any response with a good explanation on the internals of the parameters would be very useful.